# convert split to_char statement from Oracle to SQL Server in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I have some Oracle SQL statements in my java code which is often split in singular parts which makes in difficult for me to find an equivalent statement in SQL Server 2017. Here is an example:

```
if (typeId >= 1 && typeId <= 5)
        {
            sql =   "SELECT t.run_id, t.tran_id, t.tran_id sort_id, t.tran_type, t.prod_id, t.type_id, t.value, " +
                     getExtractStatement() + " (year from t.tran_datetime) y, " +
                     getExtractStatement() + " (month from t.tran_datetime) mo, " +
                     getExtractStatement() + " (day from t.tran_datetime) d, " +
                     " to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'HH24')) h, " +
                     " to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'MI')) mi, " +
                     " to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'SS')) s, " +
                     " to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'FF')) ms " +
                     " FROM tran_calc_group t, mai_group_log m " +
                     " WHERE t.run_id = m.run_id and m.group_id = 1 " +
                     " AND m.mai_class_id = %d " +
                     " AND t.result_group_id = m.level_1 " +
                     " AND t.result_group_id_2 = m.level_2 " +
                     " AND t.result_group_id_3 = m.level_3 " +
                     " AND t.result_group_id_4 = m.level_4 " +
                     " AND t.prod_id = " + query.getProdId() + 
                     " AND t.run_id IN (" + runLogIds + ")" +
                     " AND t.type_id = " + typeId;
        }
```

If it were only a usual `to_char` statement with a YYYY-MM-DD argument for example I could just use `GETDATE(), 20` in SQL Server but I don't know how to do this for such a split statement

```
" to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'HH24')) h, " +
" to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'MI')) mi, " +
" to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'SS')) s, " +
" to_number(to_char (t.tran_datetime, 'FF')) ms " +
```

I have tried to convert it with a tool (SQLines) but it did not work.

Comment: Which is the version of your SQL Server?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in SQL Server. It allows you to extract particular parts of given date and time value. For example:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
      ,DATEPART(HOUR, GETUTCDATE())
      ,DATEPART(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE())
      ,DATEPART(SECOND, GETUTCDATE())
      ,DATEPART(MILLISECOND, GETUTCDATE());
```

[image]

Also, as stated in the documentation, it returns integer, so there is no need for additional converting.